# Erro no banco não consigo salvar dados na tabela

Tags: android

to fazendo uma video aula para salvar dados no banco, já fiz 3 tutorias diferentes sempre da erro, segue a baixo o Logcat em info.

05-29 14:02:57.894 22842-22842/com.roma0x.mycash E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: adicionados
05-29 14:02:57.896 22842-22842/com.roma0x.mycash E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting nome=Teste
                                                                   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: adicionados (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO adicionados(nome) VALUES (?)
                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1472)
                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1343)
                                                                       at com.roma0x.mycash.Activity.AdicionarActivity.onCreate(AdicionarActivity.java:69)
                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6760)
                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:159)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6139)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que o sistema não está encontrando a tabela **adicionados**

"Ah! mas eu coloquei essa tabela sim, ela está lá!"

Ok, então você tem duas opções pra resolver,

**Primeira:**

Suba a versão do seu banco local, se está na versão 1, suba para 2, se estiver na 2, suba para 3 e assim sucessivamente

**Segunda:**

Desinstale a aplicação do device antes de compilar novamente, fazendo isso o banco atual será removido, e quando vc compilar irá ser instalado somente o novo, ignorando o antigo.

Espero ter ajudado!